# GET parameters in CreateView

Tags: python, django

I often use the solution of next parameter in the url to select the redirection of an UpdateView, something like that :

```
class TapUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Tap
    fields = ['number', 'container']
    template_name = 'shops/tap_update.html'
    success_url = '/shops/tap/'
    success_message = "Tap %(number)s was updated successfully"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return force_text(self.request.GET.get('next', self.success_url))
```

It works pretty well with an url `.../tap/update/?next=/users/profile`.

However, I'm trying to do the same for a CreateView and it doesn't work ...
It seems that the def doesn't receive any GET or POST parameter.

For instance on this view :

```
class SingleProductCreateView(CreateView):
    model = SingleProduct
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'price', 'shop']
    template_name = 'shops/singleproduct_create.html'
    success_url = '/shops/singleproduct/'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return force_text(self.request.POST.get('next', self.success_url))
```

The url.py :

```
url(r'^singleproduct/create/$', SingleProductCreateView.as_view(), name='url_create_singleproduct'),
```

The template `shops/singleproduct_create.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form action= "{% url 'url_create_singleproduct' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

And the template with the url :

```
...
<a href="{% url 'url_create_singleproduct' %}?next=/shops/foyer/workboard">Add a product</a>
...
```

The result is always the `success_url = '/shops/singleproduct/'` and not the next parameter.

Comment: Why don't you show the code that isn't working, rather than the code that is? And how are you passing in that next parameter? If it's from the template, you should show that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access `next` key of request.POST, but that key located in `request.GET` as in `TapUpdateView.get_success_url` method.

So in case if you would replace `SingleProductCreateView.get_success_url` from

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return force_text(self.request.POST.get('next', self.success_url))
```

to

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return force_text(self.request.GET.get('next', self.success_url))
```

Everything would work as you expect.

In case if you wish to access `next` key in `request.POST` you have to create form with `action="your view"`, `method="POST"` and attach an hidden input as in code snippet below:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'url_create_singleproduct' %}">
  <input type=hidden name="next" value="/shops/foyer/workboard" />
  <button type="submit">Go to your page</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this mistake, I tried GET or POST and same results.
The issue seems to be in the template with the form (just added)

Comment: see extended answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 

It seems to work with : 

`method="POST"` in the form

And `self.request.POST.get('next', self.success_url)`